# INDEX/MATCH MAX vba

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, max, match

My question is about finding the student name from range (D2:D296) who contains the highest value from range(N2:N296). I have done the below code and could not execute well.
My bad, I did not mentioned earlier about that my datas are from diff worksheet which is Sheet1.

Sub highestmark()

```
Dim Result As Long
Dim rng As range
Dim rnng As range


Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("$N$2:$N$296")
Set rnng= This Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("$D$2:$D$296")
Result = Index(rnng, Match(Max(rng), rng))

[B3] = Result
```

End Sub

Im kinda new to vba, i appreciate the comments earlier, again, my bad that i didnt write it down clearer just now and my bad that i write weird codes.

Comment: Code is not written.

Answer (score 2):

Well, can't see what you did, but based on your question:

```
=INDEX(D2:D296,MATCH(MAX(N2:N296),N2:N296,0))
```

Comment: Your MAX formula needs a closing bracket. I'd edit it but it tells me i must add a minimum of 6 characters.

Comment: @Gravitate thanks, well spotted, just typed it... and I'm not the best typist... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub HighestValue()

        Dim Lastrow As Long, MaxValue As Long
        Dim rngValues As Range, rngNames As Range
        Dim MaxName As String

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

            Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            Set rngValues = .Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(Lastrow, 2))
            Set rngNames = .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(Lastrow, 1))

            MaxValue = Application.Max(rngValues)

            MaxName = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(rngNames, Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(MaxValue, rngValues, 0))

        End With

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Application or WorksheetFunction if you are using native worksheet functions to VBA code.

```
Dim Result As Long
Dim rng As range
Dim rnng As range


Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("N2:N296")
Set rnng= ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").range("D2:D296")
Result = Application.Index(rnng, Application.Match(Application.Max(rng), rng, 0))

[B3] = Result
```